# Pandas: How to plot a graph with multi index with only one value in of the indexes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame([
        ('Q1','Blue',100),
        ('Q1','Green',300),
        ('Q2','Blue',200),
        ('Q2','Green',350),
        ('Q3','Blue',300),
        ('Q3','Green',400),
        ('Q4','Blue',400),
        ('Q4','Green',450),
    ], 
    columns=['quarter', 'company', 'value']
)
data = data.set_index(['quarter', 'company']).value

data.unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

When above code isrun below is the way the graph looks.

[image]

How do I plot a graph where I can see quarter on x-axis and only 1 company (either Blue or Green) on y-axis ?

I am very new to Pandas and I could not make it work. Please help me understand. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you call `unstack`, you have the following dataframe:

```
company     Blue    Green
quarter         
Q1          100     300
Q2          200     350
Q3          300     400
Q4          400     450
```

So if you want to plot just for company `Blue` for example, you can select it like any other column.

`data.unstack()['Blue'].plot(kind='bar')` creates this figure:

[image: this figure]

Answer (score 0):

When you are unstacking the data after setting index it will be converted purely into categorical values
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZcIN.png)

```
data.unstack()['Green'].plot(kind='bar',legend=True)
data.unstack()['Blue'].plot(kind='bar',legend=True)
```

you can directly delect the category that you want to plot

Answer (score 0):

Yep, these are tricky with multi-level indexes.

One solution, if possible, is to build your data frame slightly differently.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame([
        (100, 300),
        (200, 350),
        (300, 400),
        (400, 450)
    ], 
    index = ['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4'],
    columns=['Blue', 'Green']
)

# Both Blue and Green Grouped bar
data.plot.bar()

# Just Blue
data.plot.bar(x='Blue')

#Just Green
data.plot.bar(x='Green')
```

Alternatively, If you need to leave the structure as is you can use pandas [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) function to reshape the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame([
        ('Q1','Blue',100),
        ('Q1','Green',300),
        ('Q2','Blue',200),
        ('Q2','Green',350),
        ('Q3','Blue',300),
        ('Q3','Green',400),
        ('Q4','Blue',400),
        ('Q4','Green',450),
    ], 
    columns=['quarter', 'company', 'value']
)
data = data.pivot(index='quarter', columns='company', values='value')

data.plot.bar()

# Just Blue
data.plot.bar(x='Blue')

#Just Green
data.plot.bar(x='Green')
```